# overriding a method in UICollectionViewLayout in Swift with an error

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to make a change to an app that we are developing and am not a full-time iOS dev. I'm trying to get a pinterest like interface for an iOS app and am working through the tutorial here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

In their custom UICollectionViewLayout, they override `layoutAttributesForElementsinRect` but I'm getting an error from the XCode 8 compiler (although running with Use Legacy Swift Language Version set to Yes).

The error I get is: `Method does not override any method from its superclass`

The abbreviated code is:

```
class PinterestLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

  ....
  override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    // Loop through the cache and look for items in the rect
    for attributes  in cache {
      if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect ) {
        layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
      }
    }
    return layoutAttributes
  }
```

If I switch the method to private it compiles but doesn't work and if I remove the override, it gives me a conflict. I do want to override the underlying method but am not sure how to get this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the wrong method signature. This is actually the reason the `override` keyword exists. It ensures an API change will be caught like this, rather than the override silently not occurring, leading to hard to diagnose issues.

It should be

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
```

Comment: That's because the mentioned tutorial code written via Swift 2.x, not 3.0

Comment: @Ahmad Yes, that's the root cause. The error thrown by the (now) misuse of the `override` keyword is the symptom that lets you catch it.